# Intersection Observer not working with background cover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried using intersection observer with a background cover. It doesn't work. But when I tried using intersection observer with a black screen it did. I'm trying to make the images and text lazy load (fade into screen). When I used a red square my code worked. When I have background cover and used an image and text, it did not. I don't understand why this isn't working.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Mynerve&family=Nunito&family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Trelp</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header class='header'>
        <img src="images/bgImage.png" alt="Not Loading..." class="bgImage">
        <div class="bgImageScreen"></div>
        <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Not Loading..." class="logo" width="150px" height="40px">
        <div class="title">Build Your<br>Business</div>
        <div class="subText">Work with experts to create and grow<br>your business.</div>
        <a href=""><div class="learnMore"><h3>Learn More</h3></div></a>
        </header>
        <section class="section">
            <div class="businessTitle hidden">80% of Business Fail</div>
            <div class="businessText hidden">Start up businesses fail all around the world. 
                The majority of times, the business lacks funding, market research, and is poorly planned. 
                Failure could also stem from the founder having unrealistic expectations about the future of the buissnes. 
                This has become an issue, for buissnesses drive economic growth.
                Here at Trelp, we've addressed this issue, and have found a perfect solution. 
                </div>
            <img src="images/business.png" alt="Not Loading..." class="businessImage hidden"> 
            <!--<img src="" alt="Not Loading..." class="buissnesImage" width="300px" height="500">-->
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}


a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

:root {
    --black: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    --white: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.container {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    perspective: 10px;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.bgImage {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.bgImageScreen {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 102%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 102%;
    object-fit: cover;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.626), black);
}

header {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    z-index: -1;
}

.logo {
    margin: 20px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 1490px;
    z-index: 3;
}

.title {
    color: var(--white);
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 90px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 1400px;
    left: 120px;
    line-height: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.subText {
    color: var(--white);
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 1400px;
    left: 120px;
}

.learnMore {
    width: 180px;
    height: 70px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 1400px;
    left: 120px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    margin-top: 30px;
    border: 3px solid var(--white);
    background-color: var(--white);
    color: var(--black);
    border-radius: 15px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    transition: all 1s;
}

.learnMore:hover {
    color: var(--white);
    background-color: transparent;
}

.section {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150vh;
    background: var(--black);
    margin: 0px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 27px;
}

.hidden {
    transform: all 2s;
}

.show {
    opacity: 1;
}

.businessImage {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 400px;
    left: 750px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.businessTitle {
    color: green;
    font-family: 'Nunito';
    font-size: 40px;
    position: relative;
    top: 150px;
    left: 150px;
    margin: 30px;
    width: 500px;
}

.businessText {
    color: green;
    font-family: 'Nunito';
    font-size: 25px;
    width: 500px;
    position: relative;
    top: 150px;
    left: 150px;
    line-height: 40px;
    margin: 30px;
}
```

JavaScript

```
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
        if (entry.intersectionRatio >= 0.5) {
            entry.target.classList.add('show')
        } else {
            entry.target.classList.remove('show')
        }
    }) 
}, {threshold: [0.5]})

const hiddenElement = document.querySelectorAll('.hidden')
hiddenElement.forEach(el => observer.observe(el))
```

I'm trying to select .businessTitle .businessImage .businessText